# Change homeAsUpIndicator dynamically

Tags: android-actionbar, android, android-styles, android-homebutton

I build an app with four tabs and, as a consequence, four fragments. In the first fragment, I have a sliding menu and I throw with a custom icon in the actionbar. The problem is that in the others fragments, I want to stablish other custom icon to return to the first fragment but I don't know what to do...

This is my styles.xml with my custom icon for the sliding menu:

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/menu32</item>
    </style>
```

The java code works well but I don't know how to change the icon dynamically.

This is what I have:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following in your fragments:

```
Actionbar ab = getActivity().getActionBar();
ab.setIcon(icon);
```

Where `icon` is a Drawable or a resource id, when the up indicator is a part of your icon.
You can also use [setHomeAsUpIndicator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setHomeAsUpIndicator%28int%29) if you use API level > 11:

```
getActivity().getActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(resId);
```

If your API level is lower, then I suggest you make use of ActionbarSherlock.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I dont want change the icon, I want change the icon of this picture:

Comment: AFAIK `setHomeAsUpIndicator` methods are available for API level > 18.