# Change color of the actionbar's arrow dynamically

Tags: android, themes

How do I change the color of the arrow of the actionbar dynamically?
I don't want to use a theme like it was done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18816418/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-actionbars-up-arrow), because the color of my actionbar changes dynamically, too.

Is it possible?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20657463/change-homeasupindicator-dynamically), I think it will help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it programmatically easily by using homeAsUpIndicator() function that added in android API level 18 and upper.

```
ActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_yourindicator);
```

Comment: This code will not change the color, right? Except for having many different indicators?

Comment: you can use different images for changing the color

Comment: Okay, that's a possibility. Thanks :)